# Android VideoView (PhoneWindowLeaked Error)

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have a `VideoView` in my `Activity` with some TextView's and EditText below it. The Video in VideoView is loaded from server. I have to always show the `Media Controls` of VideoView. I have overriden the `hide()` in MediaController. In `OnPrepared()`, after `start()` I am setting the VideoView to `show()`. It is showing the controls which is what I wanted. I have written code to finish my activity when device back button is pressed. Now my issue is when I **press phone's back button** the **activity doesn't finish**. When I move to some other activity, it shows `PhoneWindowLeaked` exception in console. I have no clue about this. I could not find anything in google or even in this site. Please help me to solve this.

Sample code snippet is below :

```
VideoView mVideoView=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
mVideoView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return true;
   }
});
mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
   @Override
   public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mVideoView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
   }
});
mVideoView.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {
   @Override
   public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
      return true;
   }
});
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
   if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK||keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) {
      if(mVideoView.isPlaying()){
         mVideoView.stopPlayback();
         mVideoView.suspend();
      }
      finish();
      return false;
   }
   return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
mediaController = new MediaController(SampleActivity.this, true){
   public void hide() {};
};
mediaController.setMediaPlayer(mVideoView);
mediaController.setAnchorView(mVideoView);
mediaController.requestFocus();
mVideoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
Uri video = Uri.parse(getResources().getString(R.string.img_path) + csPath);
mVideoView.setVideoURI(video);
mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
   @Override
   public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
      mVideoView.start();
      mediaController.show(900000000);
   }
});
@Override
protected void onPause() {
   mediaController.hide();
   mVideoView.stopPlayback();
   mVideoView.suspend();
   super.onPause();
}
@Override
protected void onStop() {
   super.onStop();
   mediaController.hide();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: in your activity's onpause method stop the videoview

Comment: yes I did call stopPlayback() and also suspend() but of no use.

Comment: please post some of your code too and pointout the line where the exception is pointing

Comment: please check I added sample code snippet. The PhoneWindowLeaked Error is shown at the line mediaController.show(900000000);